# Add a different HTML attribute to each option in a Symfony choice field

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox, symfony-forms

I would like to make a Symfony2 Form choice list (of checkboxes), but I want each of these choices to have a different attribute, for instance:

```
<div class="field inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="form_options_0" name="form[options][]" value="1">
    <label for="form_options_0" data="1">Option 1</label>
</div>
<div class="field inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="form_options_1" name="form[options][]" value="2">
    <label for="form_options_1" data="2">Option 2</label>
</div>
```

I tried looking at the Symfony Form docs but it looks like you can only add custom attributes to the choice field as a whole, rather than the individual options.
Does anyone know if this is possible without creating a custom field type or view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a colleague of mine had a solution for this. It's not ideal but we worked around this by creating a macro in the twig template like so:

```
{% macro renderOptions(options) %}
  {% set length = options|length %}
  {% for key in 0..(length - 1) %}
    {{ form_row(options[key], {'attr': {'data': options[key].vars['value'] } })}}    
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

and then calling it like so:

```
{{ _self.renderOptions(form.options) }}
```

Obviously, you would need to adjust the logic and maybe pass in different variables depending on what values you want to inject, but the basic logic is here. Loop through each option and give it an attribute. Worth noting that the macro exists independently of the rest of the template just like a regular function.

Answer (score 3):

In more recent version of Symfony (I think since 2.7) there is a new option called [choice_attr](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr) to do what you need

Example from the doc:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
// ...

$builder->add('attending', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array(
        'Yes' => true,
        'No' => false,
        'Maybe' => null,
    ),
    'choice_attr' => function($val, $key, $index) {
        // adds a class like attending_yes, attending_no, data-*, etc
        return [
             'class' => 'attending_'.strtolower($key),
        ];
    },
));
```